# finding unique combinations of elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

Having a lot of trouble figuring this out.  I have a list of lists.   The first element of each individual list is a name.  The second element is a sports team (just for fun).

```
[['bryan', 'celtics'],
 ['bryan', 'bobcats'],
 ['bryan', 'wolves'],
 ['steve', 'celtics'],
 ['steve', 'kings'],
 ['steve', 'hawks'],
 ['david', 'celtics'],
 ['david', 'wolves']
 ['david', 'heat']]
```

I'm essentially trying to find the unique combinations of two teams for each person - essentially, answering the question, what two teams were the most common among individual players.  So for bryan, there are three teams and the possible combinations are ['celtics', 'bobcats'], ['bobcats', 'wolves'], ['celtics', 'wolves'].

One output I could use, which I've been trying to get, is a another list of lists like this:

```
[['celtics', 'bobcats'],
['bobcats', 'wolves'],
['celtics', 'wolves'],
['celtics', 'kings'],
['celtics', 'hawks'],
['kings', 'hawks'],
['celtics', 'wolves'],
['celtics', 'heat'],
['wolves', 'heat']]
```

However, my most desirable output (the end product) would be finding the highest count of two teams.  In the example above that would be ['celtics','wolves'] with 2 occurrences (with 'bryan' and 'david')

I tried to write a for loop but couldn't quite figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.   I'd prefer not use dictionaries.

Comment: _"I'd prefer not use dictionaries."_ - why?

Comment: So, you split it into 2 sub-tasks: 1) group teams by person, 2) generate pairs for each group.

Comment: I've done this before, you need to use a recursive method. You can do it with a list, a dictionary does make the job a bitch of a pain.  I agree with @merlin2011, so I wont give you my code. Good luck!

Comment: i can use dictionaries if thats the easiest way to get it done, i have a basketball analytics blog and am doing an analysis (and teaching myself python), i'd love for someone to point me in the right direction on how to approach this with python

Comment: @merlin2011 i went to school years ago, and even if it was homework, wouldn't that be encouraged so others could learn? just trying to learn myself and couldn't find anything similar to dealing with list of lists

Comment: @Maximas okay, can you point me in the right direction?  yikes, sorry for offending everyone, just trying to learn

Comment: @user2989523 The best way I found, is to initially create the loops you need, to at least parse the first one. Generalise them enough so that they have the ability to work with all of the words, the at the end of the loops use recursion :) When I did it, I found it very painful. Just remember that you might get stuck in the same thought pattern. When that happens, just take a break and you should eventually get through it! Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps:

1) group the entries by the name. That's where [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is handy:

```
from collections import defaultdict
by_name = defaultdict(list)    # create empty lists automatically
for name, team in teams:
    by_name[name].append(team)
```

2) generate pairs from the groups using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

for group in by_name.items():
    for pair in combinations(group, 2):
        yield pair  # list(pair) if you need lists
```